# What should be ideal choice to go with Activity or the Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-bottomnav

I am implementing an Activity having BottomNavigationBar with 4 clickable items. Let's call those items as Profile, Timeline, Messages, Find Friends.
The user is taken to Activity with these 4 Option in Bottom Bar after authentication.My doubt is whether to open a fragment in the space left for these options or to open a new activity whenever user clicks on any of these options. Since, these 4 options will have completely different functionality what would be the ideal way to implement this, Activity/Fragment.

Comment: If your are planning to have your navigation bar on each new screen, I would go with fragments. Then you don't have to create a new instance of the navigation bar 4+ times.

Comment: @hopeman yes this navigation bar will always be visible after the user authentication irrespective of the option selected. So, fragment will be my go to option right?

Comment: Yes, fragments give you more flexibility here, and save you resources.

Comment: I think Fragments is perfect options for navigation bottom bar. You can refer to this link also:https://www.truiton.com/2017/01/android-bottom-navigation-bar-example/

Comment: @hopeman thanks for the answer!!

Comment: @Abhishek no worries.